# Python Scipy ndimage.gaussian_filter throwing runtime error

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, computer-vision, gaussian

#### What I am trying to do:

1. Read an image in python.
2. Apply Gaussian filter using Scipy's ndimage.gaussian_filter() function.
3. Display the resultant image.

Here is the code that I am trying to run:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

img = cv2.imread('lena.png', 0)
img = ndimage.gaussian_filter(img, sigma=(5, 5, 0), order=0)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray', interpolation='bicubic')
plt.show()
```

#### What the problem is:

I am getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: sequence argument must have length equal to input rank
```

The complete stack trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/guest/stackoverflow.py", line 6, in <module>
    img = ndimage.gaussian_filter(img, sigma=(5, 5, 0), order=0)
  File "/Users/guest/anaconda/envs/MyEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/ndimage/filters.py", line 346, in gaussian_filter
    sigmas = _ni_support._normalize_sequence(sigma, input.ndim)
  File "/Users/sguest/anaconda/envs/MyEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/ndimage/_ni_support.py", line 65, in _normalize_sequence
    raise RuntimeError(err)
RuntimeError: sequence argument must have length equal to input rank
```

Here is the image I am trying to process:
[leng.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD2xf.png)

Comment: I don't know this function, but from the error message I guess that either `img` is 2D but you give 3 values, or `order` has to have 3 values also.

Comment: @CrisLuengo's guess is correct.  By putting 0 in the second argument, you told `imread` to convert the image to grayscale.  So `img` is a 2-d array.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, you are correct. Changing the sigma to sigma=(5, 5) solved it. Would you please add that as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the stack trace, the error "sequence argument must have length equal to input rank" is thrown by the line `img = ndimage.gaussian_filter(img, sigma=(5, 5, 0), order=0)`

`sigma` is a sequence argument, and you're expected to give one value per image dimension (this is the "input rank" mentioned in the error message).

Apparently, the statement `img = cv2.imread('lena.png', 0)` returns a 2D array (the `0` argument tells `imread` to convert the image to grey-value). Thus, `gaussian_filter` needs 2 values for `sigma`, not 3.